# convert DTO to JSON

Tags: java, json, csv

I have created a class for converting the csv file to dto and then ojson structure but when I convert to json I get the last row in csv alone.

this is my code

```
public class TermParsing {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TermParsing.class.getName());
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String data;
    //creating object for the dto class
    TermParsingDTO term = new TermParsingDTO();
    CsvReader read;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    HashMap hmap=new HashMap();

    //method to parse the csv file    
    void changeFileType() throws IOException {
        try {
            //to get the properties file from the source
            FileReader file = new FileReader("./config.txt");
            //loading the properties file
            prop.load(file);
            data = prop.getProperty("File");
            String path = prop.getProperty("Path");
            //to export the log message to the target
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(path);
            log.addHandler(fh);
            //to format the log messages
            SimpleFormatter format = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(format);
            log.warning("FileNotFoundException may occur");
            //reading the input csv file
            read = new CsvReader(data);
            read.readHeaders();
            //to obtain the values from csv file 
            while (read.readRecord()) {
                term.setTerm_Name(Arrays.asList(read.get("Term Name")));
                term.setParent_category(Arrays.asList(read.get("Parent Category")));
                term.setShort_description(Arrays.asList(read.get("Short Description")));
                term.setLong_description(Arrays.asList(read.get("Long Description")));
                term.setStatus(Arrays.asList(read.get("Status")));
            }                
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TermParsing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "FileNotFoundException", ex);
        }
    }
```

here in this method  my json structure is created for a single value alone

```
void convertToJson() throws IOException {            
    ObjectMapper map = null;
    String jsonInString;
    map = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonInString = map.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(term);
    System.out.println(jsonInString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you read all lines independently ?

```
TermParsingDTO term = new TermParsingDTO();
```

This should be :

```
List<TermParsingDTO> terms = new ArrayList<>();
```

And at the end of your loop:

```
terms.add(term);
```

Then all your records would be within your list.

Comment: when it is done the last value is repeated.  {
  "Term" : [ {
    "term_Name" : "TermBulk9",
    "parent_category" : "Parent Category>>Cat s",
    "short_description" : "Test Term",
    "long_description" : "Term used for testing",
    "status" : "Standard"
  }, {
    "term_Name" : "TermBulk9",
    "parent_category" : "Parent Category>>Cat s",
    "short_description" : "Test Term",
    "long_description" : "Term used for testing",
    "status" : "Standard"
  },
  ]
}all  the values are not displayed